# R Cummulative sum in second column and offset

Tags: r, cumsum

These are the values in my column

```
Col1
0.83
2.01
1.74
2.26
1.85
```

I am trying to create a second column which is a form of cummulative sum values from Col1 , the expected results should like this below

```
Col1    Col2
0.83    -
2.01    7.86
1.74    5.85
2.26    4.11
1.85    1.85
```

This is the logic behind the values in Col2

```
7.86 <-  2.01 + 1.74 + 2.26 +  1.85
5.85 <-  1.74 + 2.26 +  1.85
4.11 <-  2.26 +  1.85
1.85 <-  1.85
```

Any suggestions on achieving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a `rev` and then do the `cumsum`

```
c(NA, tail(rev(cumsum(rev(df$Col1))), -1))
#[1]   NA 7.86 5.85 4.11 1.85
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0.83, 2.01, 1.74, 2.26, 1.85)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```

Comment: seems like NA values are tripping up the cumsum, is there a way to ignore the NA ?

Comment: @Science11 The `NA` values are appended at the end.  It is not changing the input

Comment: Cool that will do

Comment: @Science11 If you meant that there are `NA` elements already in the column, then may need to replace it with `0` or so (depends on what the expected output is)